# Using WordPress ACF repeater in header.php

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Within ACF, I have a repeater called "slider" with a radio button field. This appears on the homepage of the site.

I'd like to output the radio button field within header.php. Here's what I'vd tried:

```
<?php
  if( have_rows('slider',$post->ID) ):
  while ( have_rows('slider',$post->ID) ) : the_row();
    if(get_sub_field('logo_type',$post->ID) == 'light' ) {
      echo '<p>Light</p>';
    }
  endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

This is coming up empty even when I try `var_dump(get_sub_field('logo_type',$post->ID));`

I've also tried:

```
<?php
  if( have_rows('slider',$post->ID) ):
  global $wp_query;
  $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
  while ( have_rows('slider',$postid) ) : the_row();
    if(get_sub_field('logo_type',$postid) == 'light' ) {
      echo '<p>Light</p>';
    }
  endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I already doing a loop here if you want take a look. https://github.com/miguelcalderons/ACF_SwiperSlider/blob/master/Template.php

Comment: have you referenced `global $post;`?

Comment: @Aibrean I have indeedy, but this still isn't playing ball. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without this $post->ID

```
<?php
 if( have_rows('slider') ):
  while ( have_rows('slider') ) : the_row();
   if(get_sub_field('logo_type') == 'light' ) {
      echo '<p>Light</p>';
   }
  endwhile;
 endif;
?>
```

Comment: You need to add $post->ID for custom fields to work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't answer your question there :P Yep, tried without `$post->ID`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but [get_sub_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/) second parameter should not be the post id but the format value. So you would leave it empty in this case.

```
<?php
  if( have_rows('slider',$post->ID) ):
  global $wp_query;
  $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
  while ( have_rows('slider',$postid) ) : the_row();
    if(get_sub_field('logo_type') == 'light' ) {
      echo '<p>Light</p>';
    }
  endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

I also recommend debugging what ID you're getting from $postid.

```
<?php
  global $wp_query;
  $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
  echo $postid;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add your custom field along with menu. i.e. create field group with header and assign menu is equal to your header menu name and then call that field using following code

```
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object('menuid');//replace with your menu id.
    the_field('logo_type',$menu);
```

you can access it anywhere and you can see this field in Apperance->Menus->Menu-name->acf-field-name

Comment: I'm trying to use the ACF repeater field within header.php, outside the loop. Menus shouldn't need to tie into this.

Comment: than you can create option page for that field if you have some common setting which you want to use in multiple pages.

Comment: Otherwise you can't use it in template other than assigned template in group.

Comment: The field needs to be controlled on the homepage, so using an options page won't work for the client.